# Optimization of the cost of a building

Tags: calculus, optimization, area, volume

I'm having problems with optimizing the total surface area of a building to find the minimal dimensions and the equation I came up with is a bit too hard to optimize (I'm a high school student) and I am stuck and don't know what to do. I have provided a link with the image and the variables.

[The sketch of the building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmB0Q.png)

$$
A_{total}=2a+2b+4h+bh_{roof}+2ac
$$

As you can see, the equation has 5 variables. I also have an equation for the volume, if that helps:
$$
V_{total}=ab\left(h+h_{roof}\over 2\right)
$$

I've tried to solve it using a particular volume but that didn't help since there are still many variables. I have heard about the Lagrange method but I don't know very much about it and couldn't use it therefore.

Thanks in advance, your help is very much needed :)

Comment: Why did you roll back my edits?  I think the formulas look a lot better in my version, no?

Comment: oh, I'm so sorry, I didn't see your edits and added something else, can you do it again :/

Comment: In any case:  I don't see anything pertaining to cost.   Usually in these problems, we have a cost function in terms of the various dimensions and the problem is to optimize some test function for a fixed cost, or some variant of that.

Comment: I've rolled back the edits.  Of course, feel free to edit this version If you want to add detail or to correct an error if I have introduced one.

Comment: yes, the cost is not included. the minimal dimensions, therefore minimal cost which will later be calculated, is what I need at this point. should've changed the question, sorry

Comment: But...how can we know if one design costs less than another if we don't know how the cost is reckoned?

Comment: i don't understand, can you elaborate? shouldn't the minimal dimensions mean minimal cost? what is the importance of the cost function at this point?

Comment: Minimal dimensions are all $0$.  Probably not the house you want to make.

Comment: yes, but what if there is a certain volume it has to reach?

Comment: You didn't specify that.  Yes, it makes sense to look for the maximal surface area with a given volume.  But then "cost" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I should say:  your formulas need some work.  They do not have the correct dimensions. $2a$, say, has the dimension of length, so your formula for $A_{total}$ doesn't make sense.